# Is there a provisioning API for Office 365?

Tags: api, office365

For hosted exchange and HMC resellers, there used to be a provisioning API to create, manage organizations, users and provision services.

Is there a similar provisioning api or portal for Office 365 resellers or partners?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have been looking for the same thing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups

Answer (score 5):

A little late but still valid. The commandlets powershell uses and potter talked about just use webservices to do their job. Just use fiddle to monitor them. Do not expect any documentation for them though

url

https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/provisioningwebservice.svc

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that there are two mechanisms:

1. Use Forefront Identity Manager to Sync from an on-premise identity store (e.g. AD). There is a nice overview [here](http://mikecrowley.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/office-365-dirsync-x64-installation-walkthrough/). This results in the richest end user experience, as it can maintain global address lists.
2. Use the [Powershell cmdlets for Office 365](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/hh125002.aspx). This allows general administration and provisioning tasks to be carried out on-premise, calling into these cmdlets. Note that there are a couple of pre-reqs, namely the Online Services Sign-in Assistant.

It would be great if MS exposed a web service to perform these admin tasks, but at current time of press, there is not one available.

Comment: More recent article, replacing the link in point 1 https://mikecrowley.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/upgrading-dirsync-to-the-latest-version/

Answer (score 1):

Graph API is also available for Office 365 User provisioning.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn130117.aspx