# Buy O365 SKU license via Graph API

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I've got working C# code that assigns O365 users with a license for one of our O365 SKUs. This code is executed via a Slack Bot.
Now we ran into an issue that we didn't have any available licenses left.

Previously, when going through this process via the O365 portal, I was able to just say "get a license, I agree" and we had +1 licenses.
Searching through the Graph API I wasn't able to find anything similar.

Is there really no way to use the API to buy another license for a SKU?

Thanks,
David

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible via the Graph API. There is an old question here on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566736/is-there-a-provisioning-api-for-office-365) which points to a web service at https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/ProvisioningWebService.svc, but an official API would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Graph cannot be used to purchase additional subscriptions or service plans for your tenant. It can only be used to assign existing licenses which have been provisioned in your tenant.

Also, there is no public API which supports these sorts of calls. Unfortunately, if you want to add a subscription for a service in your tenant, you must use our public UX. In this situation, for adding Office 365 subscriptions, you should use the [Office Portal](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Buy-another-Office-365-for-business-subscription-fab3b86c-3359-4042-8692-5d4dc7550b7c).

Comment: This is unfortunate as it really breaks our workflow to assign licenses to users from Slack. This means that we can't do Just-in-time provisioning of users, because at some point someone needs to log on to the portal and purchase a license. Everything else is automated via Slack, creating the user in O365, adding to groups, assigning existing license. Just the bit to purchase a license if we ran out of licenses doesn't work.